# Vue interceptor not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My `Vue interceptor` is not working properly.

In my console I receive the error:

```
[VueResource warn]: Invalid interceptor of type object, must be a function
```

My **main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import Resource from 'vue-resource';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App.vue';
import LoginView from './components/LoginView.vue'

Vue.use(Router);
Vue.use(Resource);

var router = new Router({
    history: true
});

router.map({
    '/': {
        name: 'login',
        component: LoginView
    }
});

router.redirect({
    '*': '/'
});

Vue.http.interceptors.push({

  request (request) {
    NProgress.start();

    const token = auth.getToken();
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;

    request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="token"]').content;

    return request;
  },

  response (response) {
    NProgress.done();

    if (response.status == 404) {
      router.go('/');
    } else if (response.status == 401 && response.data.refreshed_token) {
      // If you received 401 "Unauthorized" response
      // with a refreshed_token in the payload,
      // this means you've got to refresh your token
      auth.setToken(response.data.refreshed_token);
    }

    return response;
  }
});


router.start(App, 'app');
```

Why is my interceptor not working?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using an old API, it has changed in recent versions.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#interceptors